# preg_replace to include "+" symbol IF used

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, posts

My current code is:

```
$epattern[17] = "/@(\\w+)/"; 
$ereplace[17] = "<a href=viewprofile.php?username=$1><font color=royalblue><b>@\\1</b></font></a>";
$postinforawb = preg_replace($epattern,$ereplace,$postinfo);
```

With the above code the text will highlight blue where the @ symbol was used up to where a space has been entered. However I now also want it to include the "+" symbol in posts. So that the following would highlight blue: "@First+Second"

What am I needing to add to the replace?

Comment: What's your input? What's your current output? What should the current output be?

Comment: And you don't need `\\\` in regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do in your case:

```
$epattern[17] = "/@([\w\+]+)/";
```

But i prefer this one as you are only allowing alphabet and `+`:

```
$epattern[17] = "/@([a-zA-Z\+]+)/";
```

Comment: It also allows numbers, have used the top part and is just what I needed, thankyou @sabuj

Answer (score 1):

```
$epattern[17] = "/@([\w\+]+)/";
```